# R Shiny textoutput and wordcloud not displaying

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframes- DF4 for terms and regression coefficients

```
 DF4
       variable    sum.estimate.
       A           0.7685268935
       with        0.2454782079
       offers      0.0586034657
       for         0.0563342240
       you         0.1297090046
       exclusive   0.1357726776
       offer       0.1922095907
       gift        -0.0100579666
       pay         0.1733257543
```

The above is imported as a datframe in R. next we create a shiny dashboard

```
 if (interactive()){
     ui<- fluidPage(textInput("e-mailSubject", 
                    label = "SubjectLine",
                    placeholder = "'"),actionButton("do", "Click Me"), 
           mainPanel(textOutput(outputId = "CTR", 
                                container = "SPAMSCORE",inline = "Left" ),
                     plotOutput("Plot1")))
```

The server has an input. The input is the text in textInput. The subject line is converted to a term document matrix and then we use a lookup to get an output value- outputtable.

```
 server<-function(input, output, session, DF4) {
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
         set.seed(1234)
         wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
         max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
         colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))   })  


   text2<-reactive({input$e-mailSubject
   mycorpus2<-Corpus(VectorSource(text2))
   mycorpus2<-tm_map(mycorpus2, tolower)
   mycorpus2<-tm_map(mycorpus2, removeNumbers)
   mycorpus2<-tm_map(mycorpus2, removeWords, c(stopwords("english")))
   #Encoding(text) <- "UTF-8"
   dtm2<-TermDocumentMatrix(mycorpus2)
   m2<-as.matrix(dtm2)
   v2 <- sort(rowSums(m2),decreasing=TRUE)
   d2 <- data.frame(word = names(v2),freq=v2)
   outputtable<-DF4[DF4$variable%in%d2$word,]
   return(output)

    })
   output$Output1=renderPrint({sum(outputtable$estimatesum)})
   }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have corrected the code and now the wordcloud appears. I am getting an error in my text output saying
error: object 'outputtable' not found

I have been stuck on this part for a few hours. I request someone to take a look and guide me.

Comment: A few things: `renderText` is for output not input. 2) You need to wrap the text processing in a `reactive` statement otherwise server.R won't "listen" for input. 3) you access data input using `input$e-mailSubject`. Label is just for the ui not the server.

Comment: I have made the following changes in the code. Now  the error seems fixed. I am still not getting the output needed

Comment: 1) your ui is missing `sidebarLayout` and `sidebarPanel`. You have incorrect parameters set for `container` and `inline`. You cannot call `text2` with out assigning it first within the reactive statement. I would suggest you read the shiny tutorial: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/#first-app